# Financial year data with default future months value mysql query

Tags: mysql, join

I am generating chart for financial year 2018-2019 (April to March) and for that I am fetching average total of sales of each month. I want to get data for entire financial year even if the data is not available for future month because in graph i have used combined bar graph so this is 1 part of it and other will be added similarly. Using below query I am only getting average total for the months of which data is inserted in the database but I need all the financial year data like below.

**Required Response -**

```
"sales" : [
    {
        "yearMonth" : "2018-04",
        "netTotal" : "154800.0"
    },
    {
        "yearMonth" : "2018-05",
        "netTotal" : "450410.0"
    },
    {
        "yearMonth" : "2018-06",
        "netTotal" : "124780.0"
    },
    {
        "yearMonth" : "2018-07",
        "netTotal" : "98750.0"
    },
    {
        "yearMonth" : "2018-08",
        "netTotal" : "0.0"
    },
    {
        "yearMonth" : "2018-09",
        "netTotal" : "0.0"
    },
    and so on till (March) 31-03-2019.....
]
```

**Query1 -**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(quotationDate, '%Y-%m') AS yearMonth, AVG(netTotal) as netTotal FROM
quotation_master WHERE companyId = '1' AND fiscalYear = '2018-2019' GROUP BY yearMonth
```

**Query2 -**

```
SELECT meses.month, CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', meses.month) as yearMonth, IF(AVG(netTotal) IS NULL, 0, AVG(netTotal)) as netTotal FROM(
        SELECT 01 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 02 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 03 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 04 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 05 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 06 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 07 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 08 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 09 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 10 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 11 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 12 AS MONTH
) as meses
LEFT JOIN quotation_master QM ON meses.month = MONTH(quotationDate) 
WHERE QM.companyId = '1' AND QM.fiscalYear = '2018-2019' GROUP BY yearMonth
```

**Query Output -**
As data till July month is available, it gives me that data only and not for other months like August, Sep, Oct and so on. I know that data is not there in the database for future months and that's why i like to get 0.0 as default value for future months.

```
"sales" : [
        {
            "yearMonth" : "2018-04",
            "netTotal" : "154800.0"
        },
        {
            "yearMonth" : "2018-05",
            "netTotal" : "450410.0"
        },
        {
            "yearMonth" : "2018-06",
            "netTotal" : "124780.0"
        },
        {
            "yearMonth" : "2018-07",
            "netTotal" : "98750.0"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I suggest using `COALESCE(AVG(netTotal), 0.0)` instead of `IF(AVG(netTotal) IS NULL, 0, AVG(netTotal))` for performance/readability sake. Keep in mind that MySQL removes the `NULL` grouped columns from the aggregate calculation, if you want to account for those use `AVG(COALESCE(netTotal, 0.0))` instead. [SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11375a/2) difference of `AVG(1, NULL) = 1 or 0.5`.

Comment: @fyrye Thanks for the suggestion, will replace it with your suggestion BUT do you have any idea how I will get default values for all months including future months. I am not getting that right now as well. Also do i need to add dates for financial year like 2018-04-01 to 2019-03-31?

Comment: I would be tempted to handle the missing dates in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, the issue is within your `WHERE` criteria.
Since your `WHERE` applies the criteria to the initial `FROM` table and filters out the returned dataset.

To resolve the issue simply replace `WHERE` with `AND` on your `JOIN ON` criteria, to limit the filtered dataset of only the joined table data.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3181f0/2

Table Schema and Data:

```
 CREATE TABLE quotation_master 
        (`companyId` int, `quotationDate` datetime, `netTotal` int, `fiscalYear` varchar(10))
    ;

INSERT INTO quotation_master 
    (`companyId`, `quotationDate`, `netTotal`, `fiscalYear`)
VALUES
    (1, '2018-04-01 00:00:00', 154800.0, '2018-2019'),
    (1, '2018-04-02 00:00:00', 154800.0, '2018-2019'),
    (1, '2018-05-01 00:00:00', 450410.0, '2018-2019'),
    (1, '2018-05-02 00:00:00', 450410.0, '2018-2019'),
    (1, '2018-06-01 00:00:00', 124780.0, '2018-2019'),
    (1, '2018-06-02 00:00:00', 124780.0, '2018-2019'),
    (1, '2018-07-01 00:00:00', 98750.0, '2018-2019'),
    (1, '2018-07-02 00:00:00', 98750.0, '2018-2019')
;
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  meses.month, 
  CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-', meses.month) as yearMonth, 
  COALESCE(AVG(netTotal), 0) as netTotal 
FROM(
        SELECT 01 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 02 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 03 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 04 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 05 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 06 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 07 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 08 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 09 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 10 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 11 AS MONTH
        UNION SELECT 12 AS MONTH
) as meses
LEFT JOIN quotation_master QM 
ON meses.month = MONTH(quotationDate) 
AND QM.companyId = '1' 
AND QM.fiscalYear = '2018-2019' 
GROUP BY yearMonth;
```

Results

```
| month | yearMonth | netTotal |
|-------|-----------|----------|
|     1 |    2018-1 |        0 |
|    10 |   2018-10 |        0 |
|    11 |   2018-11 |        0 |
|    12 |   2018-12 |        0 |
|     2 |    2018-2 |        0 |
|     3 |    2018-3 |        0 |
|     4 |    2018-4 |   154800 |
|     5 |    2018-5 |   450410 |
|     6 |    2018-6 |   124780 |
|     7 |    2018-7 |    98750 |
|     8 |    2018-8 |        0 |
|     9 |    2018-9 |        0 |
```

---

Note: As mentioned in my comment, be sure to test the desired results of `COALESCE(AVG(netTotal), 0)` as opposed to `AVG(COALESCE(netTotal, 0))`, as MySQL skips the `NULL` aggregate columns and would not account for rows that exist but are `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @fyrye for investing your valuable time for me and its working absolutely fine. I really appreciate your kind gesture :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `WHERE` clause. Since there is no data in the database for those future months, the test of `QM.companyId = '1' AND QM.fiscalYear = '2018-2019'` will fail since both those values will be `NULL`. Try changing the `WHERE` clause to

`WHERE QM.companyId = '1' AND QM.fiscalYear = '2018-2019' OR QM.companyId IS NULL`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the above change is not working & doesn't return values for future months. I think i have to somewhere define the dates (start and end) as well, because without that how it will recognize the duration?

Comment: Strange... it works fine for me with a small test [case](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee3308/14). Do you have a test case?

Comment: Did you look at my [test case](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee3308/14)? How does it differ from what you are doing? As you can see it gives values for all months, even when there aren't any in the database.